# How to set the file order (arrangement) permanently in Finder?

Tags: finder

I use High Sierra and each time I have to set the file order to "Date modified" but then the next time it defaults back to "None".

Any way to set it permanently for all folders?

Comment: for which folder ? The OS X folders do not have that setting, only your folders.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Just to clarify, are you saying that when you set it to sort by *Date modified* that this doesn't stick for the same folder? Or are you wanting to set this as default behaviour for all folders so you don't have to set it for each one manually?

Comment: Yes it doesn't stick for the same folder. Setting it permanently for one folder would be great, but permanently for all folders even better.

Answer (score 5):

All folders except the Applications folder and its sub-folder will maintain your setting for `Date Modified` if so set in the

> Arrange pull down menu

[image]

[image]

The Applications folder does not even has such a option.

However, if you're talking about the "Sort By" option, when you're in a folder press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to see the View options.

Now go about setting the view options exactly how you'd like them to be. Once completed, click on the <kbd>Use as Defaults</kbd> button at bottom centre of the View options window. This will set your configuration as the default for all folders.

Comment: There may be some confusion here, but the *Date Modified* option is available across the board (though it's not necessarily available by default). That is, it does appear for me in my Applications folder.

Comment: @Monomeeth that is correct as Coulomb, but it does not appear in the `Arrange` pull down menu for Applications folder.

Comment: This is where I think there's some confusion - not sure if it's on my part or yours - but where do you get the question is about the `Arrange` (or `Group`) option in the *Applications* folder? I'm thinking they're talking about the `Sort By` option, although we may need the OP to clarify as the question is a little ambiguous.

Comment: @Monomeeth maybe i misunderstood the question. There are two level of sorting order, the Top (first one) is under the ARRANGE BY which should always arrange by !!.... the second one is just clicking on the top of the coulombs to order. But I'll stand corrected by OP clarification. Why is that one switching to NONE, I do not know.

Comment: That's fair. I've just edited your answer to cover for the "Sort By" option, but please feel free to roll it back if you don't want this in your answer.

Comment: @Monomeeth thank you, you added clarity, lets see what OP says.

Comment: Thanks but I don't see a "Set as Defaults" button.

Comment: select file, hold Command and press J, a new window will open, at the bottom of it there is the Set as Default